# Ext JS 4: Sencha CMD issues

Tags: extjs, amazon-ec2, extjs4, sencha-cmd

Ok, I've been trying and trying my hardest to build a simple application with the Sencha CMD tool. I've tried this with versions 4.0.7 (located on Sencha website), 4.1.0 ([here](http://learningextjs.googlecode.com/files/ext-4.1.0-gpl.zip)), 4.1.1 ([here](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1-gpl.zip)), and 4.2.1 (Sencha website) with varying results but no success. When I issue the commands:

```
sencha -sdk extjs-4.0.7 generate workspace ext407
sencha -sdk extjs-4.1.0 generate workspace ext410
sencha -sdk extjs-4.1.1 generate workspace ext411
```

I get a directory with only the empty directory **packages**. As I've read the documentation, my directories should have **ext** and **packages**. When I issue `sencha -sdk ext-4.2.1.883 generate workspace ext421`, I get the proper folders. However, when I take the next step:

```
cd ext421
sencha -sdk ext generate app ThemeDemoApp appDemo
```

per the [Theming Guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming), it appears to fail, even though I get my ext421 directory. I say it appears to fail because this is the error I get:

> [INF] Loading classpath entry /var/www/html/applications/web/ext421/ext/src
>
> /home/ec2-user/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342/sencha: line 58: 19461 Killed
>
> java $jvmArgs -jar $BASEDIR/sencha.jar "$@"

And it looks like my **sass/config.rb** is a bit unfinished...

```
cur_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
output_style = :nested
```

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3, Sencha CMD 3.1.2.342, and Java 1.7.0_25. I'm also on a 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI instance.

I'm so confused what the problem is... I have this working on my work laptop (Mac OSX Lion), but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong on my ec2 instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cross posted from [Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271854-Sencha-CMD-problems...).

Comment: The problem may be that I checked out the open-sdk version of Java from Yum... I'll try downloading directly from Oracle's website and report back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what I did, but I diffed `sencha` and `sencha-3.1.2.342`... the only difference was the end of the file, indicating that the `sencha` binary did not have a newline at the end.  I did a `hexdump` on both of the files, and sure enough, it did not.  I edited the file and added one by just hitting return at the end of the file.  This seemed to make the file happy.

Now, I've gone back and removed this newline, and the file still runs.  Baffling.  I have no idea why it's working... I even went back and re-ran the installer, now it works.  Maybe I'm just going crazy?

There's been a great deal of discussing this topic in the [Sencha thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?271854-Sencha-CMD-problems...) I started... it kind of sounds like Java is running out of memory, but we're not 100% sure on this diagnosis.  If someone comes up with a better answer, I'll mark that.

Answer (score 0):

- Why do you need to generate workspaces and applications on EC2 instance? Use source control repository instead, generate the files once on your laptop and check them in so you don't have to repeat this every time
- Sencha Cmd is compatible with Ext JS 4.1.1a+ and 4.2.x, so no luck with other versions
- Not quite sure about Ruby compatibility issues, their versioning system is weird; in Linux Cmd worked for me with Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Sencha Cmd is compatible with Ext JS 4.1.1... as that's what I used as the SDK on my Mac laptop.  And I think when I started using Cmd on my Mac, it told me to use a different version of Ruby (2.0 at that time), so I switched to 1.9.3 and all was fine.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; I confirmed with Cmd devs and indeed Cmd 3.1.x is compatible with Ext JS 4.1.1a and above. Re: Ruby compatibility, I'm no expert at that and can only report my experience. I tried Sencha Cmd with CentOS 6.4 and it worked with Ruby 1.8.7 that came with the system. Not sure what flavor of Linux Amazon is using.

Comment: Just curious, what version of Java are you running, and is it the openSDK version?

Comment: I had no problems with both Oracle JDK and OpenJDK 1.7 in CentOS.

Comment: Interesting... so I installed Oracle's JDK and still got that error.  However, instead of using the `sencha` binary, I used the `sencha-3.1.2.342` binary and all seemed well.  Dunno what the difference between those two are...